# What is the easiest way to keep track of scores?

Tags: ios, nsinteger, cgfloat

I'm looking to have a system where it updates the score the user has if they get the answer right in a multiple choice question. I have an IBAction that runs when the user selects the right choice and I want it to update the score.
i.e. score + 2 when answer is correct
Is it something with CGFloat or NSInteger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//.h File
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger score; //If the user can get a negative score, change "NSUInteger" to "NSInteger"
-(void)scoreChanged;

//.m File
-(void)scoreChanged{
    self.score += 2; //You can change the 2 to any number
}

//viewDidLoad
self.score = 0;
```

Wherever you want to update the score, just call the `scoreChanged` method. Hope this helps!